# Some basic HTTP protocol questions (programming and theory)

Tags: objective-c, qt, http, sockets, stream

Before you decide its a tl:dr (too long, didnt read) post try to read at least some, since Its a question broken down in a lot of small pieces. Some of which you can probably answer and help me.

Please try to help me as much as you can. These types of problems are very common on the internet and I think you will help me and much more people after me.

I am currently researching HTTP services and the protocol itself so that I can discover if it is useful to me.
I have some basic questions as well as some code that needs to be discussed.

First I would like to know how does the communication start? I have discovered that the client sends a message in which it requests a resource (is this correct?). Then what happens? I (as a server) have to reply with what?
Do I need to append a carriage return and a line feed after every response? Somewhere it says there even need to be two (\r\n\r\n).
How can an asynchronous writing be established? (I hope this question is understandable) My primary goal is to achieve a connection between a client and a server and then a continuous data stream from server to the client. Does the client need to reply for every message it gets?
I hope I made my questions clear, since I'm not an expert in these things (yet, I am very interested in it).

And for the programming part of my problem.
I have managed to put together a simple program in Qt in C++ (server side) and a simple client in Objective C (iOS). The client connects and I can read the request header. It is like this:

```
Data available, incoming:  "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9990
Connection: close
User-Agent: CFStream%20test/1.0 CFNetwork/609 Darwin/12.2.0
```

Should I reply to this header manually? And if so, what?

The client side code looks like this (i know its not pseudo but i think its pretty self-explanatory):

```
- (void)setupStream
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:9990"];

    CFHTTPMessageRef message = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"GET", (CFURLRef)url, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);

    stream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(NULL, message);
    CFRelease(message);

    if (!CFReadStreamSetProperty(stream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPShouldAutoredirect, kCFBooleanTrue))
    {
        NSLog(@"Some error.");
    }

    CFDictionaryRef proxySettings = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings();
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(stream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy, proxySettings);
    CFRelease(proxySettings);

    if (!CFReadStreamOpen(stream))
    {

        CFRelease(stream);
        NSLog(@"Error opening stream.");
    }

    CFStreamClientContext context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    CFReadStreamSetClient(stream, kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred, readStreamCallback, &context);
    CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(stream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    NSLog(@"Done");
}
```

This is the setup stream method. The `stream` variable is a class variable of type `CFReadStreamRef`.

The callback looks like this:

```
static void readStreamCallback(CFReadStreamRef aStream, CFStreamEventType event, void *client)
{
    ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)client;
    [controller handleEvent:event forStream:aStream];
}
```

And the handle event like this:

```
- (void)handleEvent:(CFStreamEventType)event forStream:(CFReadStreamRef)aStream
{
    if (aStream != stream)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Handle event callback");

    switch (event)
    {
        case kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            NSLog(@"Work log");
            UInt8 bytes[11];
            CFIndex length;
            length = CFReadStreamRead(stream, bytes, 11); //I know 11 bytes is hard coded, its in testing stage now. Feel free to suggest me how to do it better.

            if (length == -1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error, data length = -1");
                return;
            }

            NSLog(@"Len: %li, data: %s", length, bytes);
        break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Other event");
        break;
    }
}
```

And thats practically all the client code that is worth mentioning. The Qt Server part (I will only post the important parts) is done like this: (this is a subclassed QTcpServer class). First the `startServer();` is called:

```
bool Server::startServer()
{
    if (!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9990))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

When there is a connection incoming the `incomingConnection` is fired off with the socket descriptor as a parameter:

```
void Server::incomingConnection(int handle)
{
    qDebug("New client connected");
    ServerClient *client = new ServerClient(handle, this); //The constructor takes in the socket descriptor needed to set up the socket and the parent (this)
    client->setVectorLocation(clients.count()); //This is a int from a Qvector in which i append the clients, its not important for understanding right now.
    connect(client, SIGNAL(clientDisconnected(int)), this, SLOT(clientDisconnected(int)), Qt::QueuedConnection); //When the client socket emits a disconnected signal the ServerClient class emits a client disconnected signal which the server uses to delete that client from the vector (thats why I use "setVectorLocation(int)") - not important right now
    clients.push_back(client); //And then I append the client to the QVector - not important right now
}
```

The `ClientServer` class constructor just creates a new socket and connects the required methods:

```
ServerClient::ServerClient(int handle, QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this); //Socket is a class variable

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));

    socket->setSocketDescriptor(handle);
}
```

Ready read just writes me the data incoming (it wont be much user later i think):

```
void ServerClient::readyRead()
{
    qDebug() << "Data available, incoming: " << socket->readAll();
}
```

And finally the write data:

```
void ServerClient::writeData(QByteArray *data)
{
    data->append("\r\n\r\n"); //I have read this must be appended to all outgoing data from a HTTP server
    socket->write(*data);
    socket->flush();
    qDebug() << "Written data to client: " << *data;
}
```

This code however does not always work. Sometimes when I write message like "Message" the client recieves all the data and some things that shouldnt be there (the new line and a wierd symbol - can `NSLog` cause this?). Sometimes when I send `"Hellow"` the client only gets `"Hel"` and some other funky stuff.

What are the problems? What should I pay more attention about? Anything that will help me will be MUCH appreciated. And please dont paste in some links that contain a book with a few hundred pages, Im sure this can be solved just by explaining things to me.

THANKS A LOT!
Jan.

Comment: Too long, didnt read :) Sorry for not puting it easier. I think its a quite common phrase. Ill fix it.

Comment: Use the qint64 write( const char*, qint64 ) overload and check its return value (number of written bytes) - you might lose data when the buffer is full and less bytes are written than you requested. Also, unless its for educational purposes, I'd strongly suggest to not implement your own HTTP stack but use an existing one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will try it out. What do you mean by "I'd strongly suggest to not implement your own HTTP stack but use an existing one"? What is a HTTP stack? And which one should I use? This is for educational purposes but if I manage to get it somewhere it may get useful outside as well.

Comment: @Majster -  Frank Osterfeld is trying to say the same thing I am.  Use a higher-level library instead of hand-coding the low-level HTTP protocol directly.  I'd go further, however: I think you should use C# or Java; or Perl, Python or Lua (each of which have very good HTTP libraries) rather than Qt.  IMHO...

Comment: Well, I definitely can't say you guys are not right. The ultimate goal is to achieve a HTTP server which would stream data to clients. I could not find anything to make my job easier and so I decided to make my own server. But now this has become a fun project and doing it low-level helps me to learn a lot about these things... And im very interested in these things :) So if you could help me complete my "quest" it would be a win-win situation :) And people after me could learn the same with everything in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked many questions ... and that's a perfectly legitimate thing to do :)

I confess - it *was* too long, I *didn't* read :(

BUT ...

1) Yes, the HTTP protocol does expect na "CRLF" ("\r\n").  Many servers and many clients are "forgiving", but strictly speaking - yes, you need them.

REFERENCE: [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

2) Wanting to understand HTTP "internals" is also perfectly legitimate - I applaud you.

One good way is to read the RFC(s).

Another is to use a "telnet" client: http://blog.tonycode.com/tech-stuff/http-notes/making-http-requests-via-telnet

Yet another is to study requests and responses in FF [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads)

3) Socket programming is another issue - which explains why sometimes you might read "hello world", and other times you might just get "hel".

Strong recommendation: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/)

4) Finally, no way would I actually write a server in Qt with C++ (except maybe as a toy "science experiment", or for some really off-the-wall requirement)

I would definitely write server code in C# (for Windows servers), Java (for everything else) or a scripting language I felt comfortable with (Perl, Ruby/RoR, Python and Lua all come to mind).

IMHO .. and hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering. 1. Ok its clear now, "CLRF" every time I write something. 2. I am shifting through RFC pages and I dont understand all the things in there, that is why im learning by trial and error. (im a 19 years old developer). 3. Socket programming - well for every request for connection I must create a socket right? 4. Well, it needs to be cross platform (C# falls here), I have no experience in Java (and i reaaaaly dont like its syntax :) ), The ultimate goal is to achieve a working program for users, so im guessing scripting falls here?
Links are much appreciated, will check them.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions pretty much amount to "how does HTTP work", and the full answer lies in [the specification](ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc2616.txt).

Comment: Yes, i know its a fair chunk of questions and code. But I do not understand everything in those RFC's.. So they are not totally helpful and I also dont always find what im looking for (the question has some socket stuff and more in it as well).

Comment: You don't need to understand everything. But if you don't know how communication starts, then have you understood anything? Go read it again.